# Test each element of string array and output boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have numpy string array that I want to test against reference string and output boolean array based on whether every element of the string array contains reference string. I have a solution but would like to have more elegant/efficient one, possibly implemented in pure python. Thanks for any input.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
myarray = np.array(['abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3'])
refstring = 'c2'
pd.Series(myarray).apply(lambda x: re.search(refstring, x)).astype('bool')

    >> 0    False
    >> 1     True
    >> 2    False
    >> dtype: bool
```

Comment: `map(lambda x: refstring in x, ['abc1', 'abc2'...])`

Comment: Thanks for the plain and simple solution @RobertSeaman

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer below if this worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment:

```
map(lambda x: refstring in x, ['abc1', 'abc2'...])
```